# I am using decode function in db2 query but I have two search values with one result value how can I optimize it

Tags: sql, db2

```
select DISTINCT 
  DECODE(
    A.FILE_MAINT_TRX_CD
  , 'LARD','DELETE'
  , 'LOBD','DELETE'
  ) AS "TRANSACTION_TYPE"
```

"how can I optimize this code as a result value in both search I am using delete"

earlier I was using case statement

```
select DISTINCT 
  CASE 
    WHEN (A.FILE_MAINT_TRX_CD = 'LARD' OR A.FILE_MAINT_TRX_CD = 'LOBD') 
    THEN 'DELETE' 
  END AS "TRANSACTION_TYPE"
```

to reduce query time I am using decode

Comment: Are you **sure** that CASE expression (or DECODE) causes your query to run slow? Is there something else in that query (especially WHERE condition which is - probably - responsible for overall performance)? By the way, how long does it take to execute so that you'd want to reduce it?

Comment: How did you determine it is the decode or case expression that slows the query? Have you got an explain plan? Why not share the full query?